# Session Doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

In my project, session is work fine before few days.But now it doesn't work. i can't find the error. plsease help me. it displays error called Severity: Notice

> Message: Undefined
>  index: firstname
>   Filename: user_include/header.php
>   Line Number: 5
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined 
>   index: id
>   Filename: user_include/header.php
>   Line Number: 7

**controller**

```
/ Check for user login process
public function user_login_process() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
//$this->load->view('admin_page');
    $this->home();
}else{
$this->load->view('user_site/login_form');
}
} else {
$data = array(
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$result = $this->login_database->login($data);
if ($result == TRUE) {

$email = $this->input->post('email');
$result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($email);
if ($result != false) {
$session_data = array(
'firstname' => $result[0]->firstname,
'email' => $result[0]->email,
    'id' => $result[0]->id,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

                    $this->load->view("user_include/header");
                    $this->load->view('user_site/index');
}
} else {
$data = array(
'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
);
$this->load->view('user_site/login_form', $data);
}
}
}





// Logout 
public function logout() {

// Removing session data
$sess_array = array(
'email' => ''


);
$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
$data['message_display'] = 'Successfully Logout';
$this->load->view('user_site/login_form', $data);
}
    }     

?>
```

**model**

```
// Read data using username and password
public function login($data) {

$condition = "email =" . "'" . $data['email'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}

// Read data from database to show data in admin page
public function read_user_information($email) {

$condition = "email =" . "'" . $email . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
return $query->result();
} else {
return false;
}
}

}

?>
```

**view**

```
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
$firstname = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['firstname']);
$email = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
$id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
} else {
header("location: login");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in you user_include/header.php , check the id and firstname are set  before you echo them out.

Comment: when i print the session array the result is

Array ( [session_id] => 9f9e42213f3dd75e1fe6d50eb4f4cc1e [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36 [last_activity] => 1440383538 [user_data] => [logged_in] => Array ( [first_name] => lak [email] => lak@gmail.com [id] => 19 ) )

Comment: When do you get the error, after or before you log in?

Comment: Your session has first_name but you session user_data was set with firstname? refer the print session that you posted.

Comment: delete codeigniter session from the browser, log in to your app and reprint session data.

Comment: now it works fine.the issue is before i filter data using user Id and session id.now its not working

Answer (score 0):

In your model replace following code by given code:

```
public function read_user_information($email) {

    $condition = "email =" . "'" . $email . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To

```
public function read_user_information($email) {
    $this->db->select('firstname, email, id');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your controller replace following code by given

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($email);
if ($result != false) {
$session_data = array(
'firstname' => $result[0]->firstname,
'email' => $result[0]->email,
    'id' => $result[0]->id,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

                    $this->load->view("user_include/header");
                    $this->load->view('user_site/index');
}
```

To

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$user_details = $this->login_database->read_user_information($email);
if ($user_details != false) {
    // Add user data in session
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $user_details);
    $this->load->view("user_include/header");
    $this->load->view('user_site/index');   
}
```

In view, replace your code by following:

```
<?php
$user_details = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']);

if ($user_details != "") {
    $firstname = $user_details['firstname'];
    $email = $user_details['email'];
    $id = $user_details['id'];
} else {
    header("location: login");
}
```

Comment: after replace your code 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: firstname

Filename: user_include/header.php

Line Number: 5

Comment: You must have firstname field on table user. Do you?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: firstname

Filename: user_include/header.php

Line Number: 32

Comment: Clear session (ctrl+shift+del) and give output of logged_in session here.